# On solution of a recursion with rectangular matrices

Tags: ds.dynamical-systems, linear-algebra, matrices, singularity-theory

Greetings to members here.
  The question is how to calculate the solution $S(k)$ of the following recursive equation
$$J(k)S(k+1)J^{T}(k)=A(k)S(k)A^{T}(k)+R(k)$$
where $J$ and $A$ are rectangular not square. $R$ is positive-definite. Furthermore, $J$ and $A$ are with full-row rank.

Comment: What is the source of this problem? Looks a lot like a discrete-time difference Riccati equation. This, and what Robert Israel said.

Comment: This is a Lyapunov equation.
We met with the problem for treating desciptor system with white noise.
$$J(k)x(k+1)=A(k)x(k)+w(k)$$

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If $J$ has more columns than rows, the map $S \to J S J^T$ is not one-to-one, so your equation does not determine $S(k+1)$.