# On solution of a discrete-time equation

Tags: discrete-mathematics, linear-algebra, matrices

Hello, members. 
I have a problem for the following problem 
when I derive an optimization algorithm for stochastic singular systems
$$S(k+1)=A(k)S(k)A^{T}(k)+R(k)+F(k)S(k+1)F^{T}(k)$$
where $R(k)>=0$
So, how to calculate $S$, is there analytic solution or numerical solution to $S$?

This problem is different from the following one
[On solution of a recursion with rectangular matrices](https://mathoverflow.net/questions/128204/on-solution-of-a-recursion-with-rectangular-matrices)

Thanks for your help

Answer (score 1, accepted):

you'll want to solve this equation iteratively, considering $S(k)$ as known and $S(k+1)$ as unknown; for $F(k)$ invertible you then have a Sylvester equation, of the form $F^{-1}(k)S(k+1)-S(k+1)F^{T}(k)=C(k)$, which has a unique solution iff $F^{-1}(k)$ and $F(k)$ have no common eigenvalue. The [Wikipedia page](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Sylvester_equation) gives algorithms to solve this equation, implemented in several software packages.

Comment: There are numerical methods dealing directly with the equation $X-FXF^T=C$, known as discrete-time Lyapunov equation, or Stein equation. There is no need to invert $F$ and convert it to a Sylvester; sometimes algorithms even go the other way round and convert a continuous-time Lyapunov equation to a discrete-time one to solve it.

Comment: Thanks for your kind help, Dr. Carlo and Dr. Federico. 

When $F$ is singular, The Sylvester method may fail to work.
So, would you please give me some links or references on the equation $X-FXF^{T}=C$. It seems we can solve it using LMI techniques for obtaining numerical solutions.

Comment: No, I made the problem too complex.
By using 'dlyap' in Matlab can solve this equation.

Comment: Yep. `dlyap` will be fine for a small-scale problem; it should use a variant of the same Bartels-Stewart method that is used for continous-time lyapunov eqs; essentially, take a Schur form of $F$ and solve directly via back-substitution for each entry of $X$ "in the right order". For large-scale problems, you can truncate the series $X=\sum_{i=0}^{\infty} F^{i}CF^{Ti}$, or obtain the partial sum truncated at the term $2^{k}$ directly from the one truncated at $2^{k-1}$ with some manipulations (Smith methods). You can apply some Möbius transforms to $F$ without changing the solution to make... 

Comment: it more stable, and ultimately obtain a discrete-time version of the ADI method for Lyapunov equations. In short, with some algebraic manipulations everything that works in the continuous-time case rates to work in the discrete-time case as well.

Comment: Very very nice comments, Dr. Federico. Thanks.

Comment: For a general linear matrix equation with more than two terms, I am not aware of any method faster than the $O(n^6)$ of the naive "vectorize everything" algorithm. (caveat: I know almost nothing of LMIs, so there might be a method in that area that I do not know about). Maybe you'll have more luck posting this as a separate question, either here or on http://scicomp.stackexchange.com/.

Comment: Let's consider a more complex situation, i.e.
$$X=F_{1}XF^{1}^{T}+...+F_{p}XF^{p}^{T}+C$$
where $p$ is an positive integer. If we augment $F=[F_{1}...F_{p}]$ and $Y=diag{X...X}$, then the equation becomes
$$FYF^{T}-[I...0]Y[I...0]^{T}+C=$$
seems like a generalized Lyapunov equation. However, there is a constraint on $Y$ for its diagonal form. How to compute $X$?

Comment: Ok, I will post it later. Maybe vecotorize method together with Kronecker product will work. Thanks a lot.